# Configure Perl DBI and DBD in Linux

Tags: linux, oracle, perl, dbi

I am new to Perl and I work in a Linux OEL 5x server. I am trying to configure the Perl DB modules for Oracle connectivity (DBD and DBI modules). Can anyone help me out in the installation procedure?

I had tried CPAN didn't really worked out.
Any help would be appreciated. I am not quite sure I need to initialize any variables other than `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `$ORACLE_HOME`

These are my observations:

ISSUE::
                I am getting the following issue while using the DBI module to connect to Oracle:

```
install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't locate loadable object for module DBD::Oracle in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at (eval 3) line 3
Compilation failed in require at (eval 3) line 3.
Perhaps a module that DBD::Oracle requires hasn't been fully installed
at connectdb.pl line 57
```

I had installed the DBD for oracle from `/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DBD/DBD-Oracle-1.50`

Could you please take a look into the steps and correct me if I am wrong:

Observations:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/opt/CA/UnicenterAutoSysJM/autosys/lib:/opt/CA/SharedComponents/Csam/SockAdapter/lib:/opt/CA/SharedComponents/ETPKI/lib:/opt/CA/CAlib
$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/usr/local/oracle/ORA
```

This is how I tried to install the DBD module:

1. Download the file DBD 1.50 for Oracle
2. Copy to /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DBD
3. Untar and Makefile.PL

.

```
Message:  Using DBI 1.52 (for perl 5.008008 on x86_64-linux-thread-multi) installed in /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI/

Configuring DBD::Oracle for perl 5.008008 on linux (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)

Remember to actually *READ* the README file! Especially if you have any problems.

Installing on a linux, Ver#2.6
Using Oracle in /opt/oracle/product/10.2
DEFINE _SQLPLUS_RELEASE = "1002000400" (CHAR)
Oracle version 10.2.0.4 (10.2)
Found /opt/oracle/product/10.2/rdbms/demo/demo_rdbms.mk
Found /opt/oracle/product/10.2/rdbms/demo/demo_rdbms64.mk
Found /opt/oracle/product/10.2/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk
Using /opt/oracle/product/10.2/rdbms/demo/demo_rdbms.mk
Your LD_LIBRARY_PATH env var is set to '/usr/local/oracle/ORA/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/usr/openwin/lib:/usr/local/oracle/ORA/ows/cartx/wodbc/1.0/util/lib:/usr/local/oracle/ORA/lib:/usr/local/sybase/OCS-12_0/lib:/usr/local/sybase/lib:/home/oracle/jdbc/jdbcoci73/lib:./'
WARNING: Your LD_LIBRARY_PATH env var doesn't include '/opt/oracle/product/10.2/lib' but probably needs to.
Reading /opt/oracle/product/10.2/rdbms/demo/demo_rdbms.mk
Reading /usr/local/oracle/ORA/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk

Attempting to discover Oracle OCI build rules
sh: make: command not found
by executing: [make -f /opt/oracle/product/10.2/rdbms/demo/demo_rdbms.mk build ECHODO=echo ECHO=echo GENCLNTSH='echo genclntsh' CC=true OPTIMIZE= CCFLAGS= EXE=DBD_ORA_EXE OBJS=DBD_ORA_OBJ.o]
WARNING: Oracle build rule discovery failed (32512)
Add path to make command into your PATH environment variable.
Oracle oci build prolog:
    [sh: make: command not found]
Oracle oci build command:
    []
WARNING: Unable to interpret Oracle build commands from /opt/oracle/product/10.2/rdbms/demo/demo_rdbms.mk.
(Will continue by using fallback approach.)
Please report this to dbi-users@perl.org. See README for what to include.

Found header files in /opt/oracle/product/10.2/rdbms/public.

client_version=10.2


DEFINE= -Wall -Wno-comment -DUTF8_SUPPORT -DORA_OCI_VERSION=\"10.2.0.4\" -DORA_OCI_102


Checking for functioning wait.ph


System: perl5.008008 linux ca-build9.us.oracle.com 2.6.20-1.3002.fc6xen #1 smp thu apr 30 18:08:39 pdt 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 gnulinux
Compiler:   gcc -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/gdbm
Linker:     not found
Sysliblist: -ldl -lm -lpthread -lnsl -lirc
Oracle makefiles would have used these definitions but we override them:
  CC:       cc
  CFLAGS:   $(GFLAG) $(OPTIMIZE) $(CDEBUG) $(CCFLAGS) $(PFLAGS)\
    $(SHARED_CFLAG) $(USRFLAGS)
       [$(GFLAG) -O3 $(CDEBUG) -m32 $(TRIGRAPHS_CCFLAGS) -fPIC -I/usr/local/oracle/ORA/rdbms/demo -I/usr/local/oracle/ORA/rdbms/public -I/usr/local/oracle/ORA/plsql/public -I/usr/local/oracle/ORA/network/public -DLINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -DSLTS_ENABLE -DSLMXMX_ENABLE -D_REENTRANT -DNS_THREADS -fno-strict-aliasing $(LPFLAGS) $(USRFLAGS)]
  build:     $(CC) $(ORALIBPATH) -o $(EXE) $(OBJS) $(OCISHAREDLIBS)
       [ cc -L$(LIBHOME) -L/usr/local/oracle/ORA/rdbms/lib/ -o $(EXE) $(OBJS) -lclntsh     $(EXPDLIBS) $(EXOSLIBS) -ldl -lm -lpthread -lnsl -lirc -ldl -lm $(USRLIBS) -lpthread]
  LDFLAGS:  $(LDFLAGS32)
       [-m32 -o $@ -L/usr/local/oracle/ORA/rdbms//lib32/ -L/usr/local/oracle/ORA/lib32/ -L/usr/local/oracle/ORA/lib32/stubs/]
Linking with /usr/local/oracle/ORA/rdbms/lib/defopt.o  -lclntsh -ldl -lm -lpthread -lnsl -lirc -ldl -lm -lpthread [from $(DEF_OPT) $(OCISHAREDLIBS)]

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/oracle/ORA/lib
Using DBD::Oracle 1.50.
Using DBD::Oracle 1.50.
Using DBI 1.52 (for perl 5.008008 on x86_64-linux-thread-multi) installed in /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI/
Writing Makefile for DBD::Oracle
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

***  If you have problems...
     read all the log printed above, and the README and README.help.txt files.
     (Of course, you have read README by now anyway, haven't you?)
```

Comment: > sh: make: command not found Your build environment appears to be broken.

Comment: `rpm -q make`??

Comment: They should be available in a repository `rpm -ivh perl-DBD-oracle` and possilby `rpm -ivh perl-DBI` if it also fails to build

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty old version of Perl (released Jan 2006). I did manage to get to work for similar versions of each component but it never passed the build tests. Besides your LD_LIBRARY_PATH (some systems use a 64-bit version) and ORACLE_HOME, I had to be careful with default character set and locale to get this to work. Be careful too of having multiple homes. In the end, I installed Oracle's Instant Client separately and defined the real instance through tnsnames.

Redoing this later with newer software was much easier on a very similar system. So, upgrade if possible or use an Instant Client for a simpler environment.

Answer (score 0):

please read this article I wrote with about [How to install DBD::Oracle](http://g14n.info/2013/07/how-to-install-dbdoracle/).

It contains all the steps required to install DBD::Oracle CPAN module, which is not a straightforward installation. The purpose is to reduce headache and turn it into a repeatable process.

Hope it can help, and also let me contribute back to the great Perl community.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.